# How to efficiently load large json with data into multiple tables on angular 8?

Tags: angular

Is there any solution to speed up loading of view with multiple tables and a lot of records in them (and omit freeze/crash of page after load)? - without solutions like infinity scroll and virtualization and pagination?

Is it possible to achieve with Angular or should I try some server-rendering for problem like that?

Comment: Yes, use pagination on the tables, and on the server side use a limit and offset on your queries

Comment: You could use a worker to process the data in another thread: https://angular.io/guide/web-worker

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to use pagination, not just client side but server side too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best solution is using pagination.
Here you have the example us how Angular Material handles the pagination for the Mat Table: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Also, if you have data that it's always the same (or rarely it's changed) you can use a Store Library to Store that data. I recommend you NGXS: https://www.ngxs.io/